# Updating a directory object changes the Content-Type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to update meta data of the directory created in ObjectStorage. Once directory was created successfully, the Content-Type was 'application/directory'. But, when i tried update the directory, the Content-Type changed to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. 
Here is my code snippet :-

```
//Create folder
$rst = $objectStorage->with('/container1/folder1')
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/directory')
        ->create();

//Update folder's metadata
$rst = $objectStorage->with('/container1/folder1')
        ->setMeta('bytes-used', 100)
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/directory')
        ->create();
```

Please advice if anything missed, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How did you check that content type change?

Could you provide the code that you are using for it or steps that you followed? because I verified that "Content-Type" is kept with:

**Content-Type: application/directory**